# Music App Now Playing View Controller Slide In Animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, ios-animations

I've been trying to recreate the animation and swiping functionality used in the music app, and trying to re-create the card view structure they use. I was wondering if anyone has done this before, or knew how apple accomplished the swipe in, swipe out features and animations. It's very responsive, you can swipe on it to open it and tap on it to animate it opening and drag it down or tap on it to close.

[image: Tap/Drag to Animate Open]
[image: Tap/Drag down to close]

Comment: Look at the implementation here: https://github.com/HarshilShah/DeckTransition/blob/master/README.md